# Ms Access - Real Time updates with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, real-time

Maybe this is beyond possible; I might be trying to get too fancy with Microsoft Access. :)

I want an Access database form to be updated in real time when an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc. is made on a table in a SQL Server database. Is there a VBA callback that will be able to be thrown if a update is made to a SQL Server table? Or is there anyway at all to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: "You use the ODBC refresh interval and Refresh interval settings to control how often Access refreshes your data. Refreshing only updates data that already exists in your datasheet or form. Refreshing does not reorder records, display new records, or remove deleted records and records from query results that no longer meet specified criteria. To view such changes, you requery the underlying records for the datasheet or form." - ref: [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Help-Access-run-faster-f6827763-bb5c-4f48-8457-7a14addab6be)

Comment: Perfect Gord! You found the exact answer I was looking for formally documented by Microsoft. Can't always get what you wish for. Thanks for researching for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I know to achieve this is to create a query like:

```
SELECT Last(TimeStamp) AS LastTimeStamp FROM [TableName];
```

When you load the form to create a Date variable (LoadedTime) which you can set to the 'LastTimeStamp' value from the query.

Using the form On Timer events run the following code:

```
If LoadedTime <> DLookup ("LastTimeStamp",[QueryName]) then
me.refresh 'or whatever action you want to take if a change is detected.
end if
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! Yes, I figured using the "OnTimer" form event would in the end be the best way to go. Tbh, I was hoping there would be some VBA event that would only trigger when update was made to the table on the server but, I figured that wouldn't be possible. I will definitely try to implement this in my application!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should link to the data, rather than import the data.  Take a look at the URL below for details.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e

Comment: Not exactly what I meant but thanks for the info! :)